# Angular update bool value in a Service with a setfunction?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

Hi i am trying to update a bool value in my service on a buttonclick through my component. I am rying to call the setfunction and then change the bool valu to the opposite value. So from true to false and when its clicked again from false to true.

***Service***

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { Melding } from "./melding";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class MeldingService {
    checkedChange: Subject<Boolean> = new Subject<Boolean>();
    private meldingen = new Array<Melding>(
        { id: 1, name: "Zinc verstopt Machine A", checked: false, roleId: 1 , beschrijving: "Ga de machine maken. dit is de beschrijving lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum "},
        { id: 2, name: "Storing Machine A", checked: false, roleId: 1 , beschrijving: "Ga de machine maken. dit is de beschrijving"},
        { id: 3, name: "Zinc verstopt Machine B", checked: false, roleId: 2 , beschrijving: "Ga de machine maken. dit is de beschrijving"},
        { id: 4, name: "Storing Machine B", checked: false, roleId: 2 , beschrijving: "Ga de machine maken. dit is de beschrijving"},
        { id: 5, name: "Defect Machine B", checked: false, roleId: 2 , beschrijving: "Ga de machine maken. dit is de beschrijving"},
        { id: 6, name: "Zinc verstopt Machine C", checked: false, roleId: 3 , beschrijving: "Ga de machine maken. dit is de beschrijving"},
        { id: 7, name: "Zinc verstopt Machine D", checked: false, roleId: 4 , beschrijving: "Ga de machine maken. dit is de beschrijving"},
        { id: 8, name: "Zinc verstopt Machine E", checked: false, roleId: 5 , beschrijving: "Ga de machine maken. dit is de beschrijving"},
        { id: 9, name: "Storing Machine E", checked: false, roleId: 6 , beschrijving: "Ga de machine maken. dit is de beschrijving"}
    );

    setChecked(id: number) {
        var melding = this.getMelding(id);
        console.log(!melding.checked);
        this.checkedChange.next(!melding.checked);

    }
}
```

***Component***

````
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

import {Melding} from "../melding/melding";
import {MeldingService} from "../melding/melding.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'ns-melding-detail',
  templateUrl: './melding-detail.component.html'
})
export class MeldingDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  melding: Melding;

  constructor(
    private meldingService: MeldingService, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.melding = this.meldingService.getMelding(id);
  }

  onButtonClick(id: number) { 
    this.meldingService.setChecked(id);
  } 
}```
````

Comment: You don't seem to be modifying the original value on button click - ```var melding = this.getMelding(id);
        melding.checked = !melding.checked;
        this.checkedChange.next(melding.checked);``` Doing so will toggle value every time.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question ? And what does `getMelding` do ?
don't mix dutch and english :)

in your `setChecked` method, are you not supposed to write `meldingen[id].checked = !meldingen[id].checked`?

Comment: There is a button on each "melding" and i am trying to update the checked value to the opposite once i click on the button